# Unable to install jenkins on ubuntu

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-16.04

When i write [sudo apt-get update]

First error : https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Packages
server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

Second error : W: The repository 'http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Update on 08 May 2023**

- I had the same issue and after some research I found the solution through official documentations.
- Users installing Jenkins LTS 2.387.1 after March 31, 2023 may see a warning or an error noting that **"the PGP key has expired"** as Jenkins LTS 2.387.1 deb and rpm files has been expire March 30, 2023.
- Jenkins LTS 2.387.2 (April 5, 2023) will resolve that warning, so long as the new PGP public key has been installed by following the instructions in the [Linux installation page](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#debianubuntu).

---

**Try these following commands :**

```
curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key | sudo tee \   /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null

echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] \   https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee \   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

---

- It will install/update all the required data.
- Then you can check jenkin server status.

---

```
service jenkins status
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a '[trusted=yes]' tag in your /etc/apt/sources.list (or sources.list.d/file) file at the line related to http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable...

At the end, in your souces.list file, you should end up with something like the following:

> deb [trusted=yes] http://pkg.jenkins.io/.....

EDIT: this shell command should do the trick:

```
sed -i 's/^deb /deb [trusted=yes] /' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then reload your apt cache with:

```
apt update
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How to open source file ???

Comment: I updated my answer with a magical command that you may execute on your linux prompt shell: sed -i 's/^deb /deb [trusted=yes] /' /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use `Your Answer` section only when you want to answer the main questions. If you want to comment on any answer, please use `Add a comment` under that answer that you want to comment on. Also, if you need more information, ask for it in the comments section rather than the `Answer` section. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow [Jenkins Debian Packages](https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/) for all the commands to install Jenkins in Ubuntu.

1. Install Java
2. Update your local package index
3. sudo apt-get install jenkins

I have installed it on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and created a [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWsA5j_pZmk&feature=youtu.be) of it.